# How to do give expire time to specific session in laravel 5.6 ?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.6

I want to create session and it should be remove at 3 days later.

How do I do that ? I checked out the documents and questions in here, but found nothing..

-what I want exactly ?

```
session()->put("suspect",true,strtotime($time_diff))
```

is that possible ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Is it easier to use the cache and store it with a tag that corresponds to the user id or session id?

Comment: @apokryfos I'm trying to mark some users as a suspect for a while. I tought creating a session value about that is enough. is there any better way to do that ?

Comment: The session is short-lived. If your user you want to flag is registered then it's easy. You can create a "flagged_at" column in your database and if a user has been flagged within the last 3 days then consider them flagged. If you want to flag non-registered users then it's hard (nearly impossible). The hard part is knowing that a user that visits your page 2 days later is the same as the one you previously flagged.

Comment: @apokryfos actually I created a `suspended_at` column in database and it checks is user  suspect or not. But I don't want to control that every time, if user already suspect, no need to check that again and again. So I decided to create a session about it. is that unneccesary ?

Comment: You can load the contents of that column in the session when a user logs in. That should be enough so you don't need to hit your database on every request if the user already has a session. However you will need to actually calculate whether the suspension is still in force on every request (it's a simple math operation, it shouldn't be too time consuming). However your approach should be that the session is a backing storage for the database (like a per user cache) so you shouldn't rely on the session value to be there, if it's not there at all you may need to read the table row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['expire'] = time() + 259200; // 3 days

if(time() > $_SESSION['expire'])
{  

 session_unset();
 session_destroy(); 

}
```

Comment: Hahaa have a great day mate